# How to load task scheduler jobs into SQL Server table

Tags: batch-file, cmd, sql-server-2008-r2

I am not expert either in command prompt or batch files building but after RND I am using the below code in command prompt mode to list the scheduler tasks into csv but I need to load these results into a SQL Server table directly instead of CSV hence again I need to develop the SSIS package to load csv results to table.

```
C:\Users\w8>schtasks /query /fo TABLE  >C:\Users\w8\Desktop\List.csv
```

Also I would like to load only where the status = running and folder=\Microsoft\Windows.NET Framework

Finally expected results in SQL Server table is

```
TaskName                                 Next Run Time          Status         
======================================== ====================== ===============
.NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319           N/A                    Running
.NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319 64        N/A                    Running
.NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319 64 Critic N/A                    Running
.NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319 Critical  N/A                    Running
```

Help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: You could query the SQL Server Agent tables (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181367(v=sql.110).aspx) and insert the results to a table. This question (http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58859/script-to-see-running-jobs-in-sql-server-with-job-start-time) has answers with some examples of the type of query I am talking about.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I want only task scheuler jobs not sqlserver agent jobs.